# Laravel dompdf table rowspan on page break not build correctly

Tags: css, laravel, html-table, dompdf, laravel-5.8

im creating export pdf using tables and rowspans, everything look just like what i want. but on page break it show like this :

[exported pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSw3N.png)

the table rowspan is not doing right

any solution for this problem?
thanks

Comment: I guess one more `td` is missing.

Comment: im using rowspan